# Jmeter: Zero minimum response time, what does it mean?

Tags: jmeter, response-time

I have Thread settings as:

1. Users: 20
2. Ramp-up: 2
3. Scheduler: 14400

My Laptop info:

```
   Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.150202-1526)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 08/18/15 02:15:18 Ver: A07.00 
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.2GHz
             Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 8096MB RAM
          Page File: 9754MB used, 6436MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per JMeter documentation:

> Min - The shortest time for the samples with the same label

Out of 89 samples sent for the label (sampler name), one or more samplers are finished with 0 seconds response time.

Total section summarizes the results of all samplers and produces the min, max and average results. As one the sampler is having 0 seconds (smallest value from all the samplers), Total also reflects the same.

I can see there are errors present for the sampler (1.12%). I would suggest save the results into csv/jtl file and check what is the error that has been thrown for the sampler. There will be entry in the results file for each sampler for each iteration/thread. so, you will find 89 entries for the sampler in the results file. You can also check that at least one sample should have 0 elapsed time, check the result code/message for that sampler(s).

To capture results:

1. Add **Aggregate Report** listener
2. In the **Filename** text field, provide the path and file name (absolute or relative path)
3. Run the test again. and check the file i.e., created in the path specified. It will contain all the entries for the all the samplers for all iterations. Check resposneCode and responseMessage fields for the samplers which gave 0 response time.

[image]

Sample results file looks like as follows:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime
1478417237227,1547,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,13762,5,5,1009,0
1478417237135,1741,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,13752,5,5,1101,0
1478417237135,1773,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,13698,5,5,1101,0
1478417238778,404,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,13698,5,5,166,0
```

Comment: Thanks Naveen two questions please: `1.` How is it possible that sampler have zero response time? `2.` Where I would find results file for each iteration?

Comment: updated the answer on how to save the results. once run the tests, analyse the resposneCode & responseMessage columns for the samplers which are having 0 response times to know why they are having 0 response times.